Migrating from MySQL 5.7 to 8 causing problems with fractional seconds
I was running a MySQL 5.7 database in AWS RDS and AWS forced me to upgrade it because I was getting charged daily for keeping an old version. So I upgraded it to 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.08.0.
I have also some old code running on Java on a Docker container, the image is openjdk:8-jdk-alpine. When running MySQL 5.7 the code was using this MySQL connector:
         <dependency>
             <groupId>mysql</groupId>
             <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>5.1.42</version>
         </dependency>

Now I have updated my code to use:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

Here is where my problems begin: I have some tables with some columns defined as datetime(3) (with three fractional seconds). For some reason, storing DateTime values with fractional seconds other than .000 works perfectly. I can save and read into/from the data base. But when I save a datetime which its fractional seconds are .000, when reading the value back from the data base, the string representation of the datetime has missing the fractional seconds, hence my datetime parse breaks because it expects the fractional part.
Here is my code for the datatime formatter:
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZoneUTC();

// MySQL DateTime -> Joda DateTime
public DateTime readingFromDB(String mysqlDateTime) {
    return formatter.withZoneUTC().parseDateTime(mysqlDateTime);
}

// Joda DateTime -> MySQL DateTime
public String savingToDB(DateTime dt) {
    return dt.toString(formatter);
}

Here is a screenshot from my DBeaver client Version 23.2.4.202311051706:

And here is a key point in all these:

From DBeaver, the values containing .000 seems to be saved without the fractional part.
From MySQLWorkbench 8.0.40 Community Edition, the values are shown as expected


The DBeaver connector driver is this one:

The MySQLWorkbench driver is this one, you can read Connector/C++ from the picture:

My code connector is com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.4.0 but I've also tried with mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33, and the issue can be reproduced from both.
The only connector that seems to work well is Connector/C++. The fact that from MySQLWorkbench (which usesConnector/C++) I can see the values as expected, explains that the Java connectors, either mysql-connector-j or mysql-connector-java, are having some kind of problem.
Does anyone know how to fix this with the Java connectors?
P.S.: I know I can hack my code adding a codition to check if the value from the DB includes the fractional part or not, but I'm trying to get to the bottom of this and give it the most possible elegant solution.

Btw, amazon aurora is not mysql, just mysql compatible. Amazon made significant changes under the hood.

This is wrong for several reasons. Leaving aside the fact that your data storage is localised as far as time is concerned, despite some hand-waving with Joda UTC routines, you are not storing instants on the timeline, (so your data are not universal), you are using old classes like Timestamp that are long superseded. There's no need to use 3rd party time libraries - since your version, you have been able to do the likes of prepStatement.setObject(1, LocalDateTime.now()); which is really the kind of thing you should be doing.

Thanks @g00se. I won't refactor this code for many reasons. I appreciate your comments, but, what do you mean by "no need to use 3rd party time libraries"? to use plain java.sql package?

Well, your mention of Joda suggests you're using that (3rd party) date library

java.time is built into your Java. It’s no 3rd party library. From Joda-Time - Home; Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310). So the suggestion is to use OffsetDateTime in UTC in Java and store it to and retrieve it from MySQL without any conversion to neither String nor Timestamp.

When using datetime(3) in MySQL and if you need a Joda-Time DateTime a quick workaround is fetching a java.time.LocalDateTime from the database and converting it using DateTime .parse(localDateTimeFromDatabase. truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS) .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC) .toString()).

How are you currently obtaining the string representations from MySQL that you pass to readingFromDB()? Are you willing to change to a more elegant way of obtaining the values from MySQL? You should not need to use strings for that.

This isn't a problem with the Connector/J, it's a problem with the implementation of java.sql.Timestamp.toString() according to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83989
That bug shows a standalone Java example of java.sql.Timestamp truncating trailing zeroes, even without fetching the value from a JDBC connection.
You can subclass java.sql.Timestamp.
Or you can cast a datetime to a string in your SQL query before it is returned in the result set.
I tested DBeaver and made it display trailing zeroes of a datetime by casting it. Here's my test query:
mysql> create table t ( id serial primary key, dt datetime(3));

mysql> insert into t (dt) values (now()), (now(3));

mysql> select id, dt, cast(dt as char) from test.t 

Here's a screenshot of the result in DBeaver, showing the non-cast dt column truncates trailing zeroes, and the column preserves trailing zeroes when I cast it to CHAR.

I'm not sure why it was working with your old version. Perhaps you were using a different JDK that implemented java.sql.Timestamp differently?

Thanks @Bill. Your answer helped me a lot. I'm testing all this locally using OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.342.07.3 (build 1.8.0_342-b07). In the cloud I run my code using Docker image openjdk:8-jdk-alpine.

It has been said many times, but you would be wise to use the same software stack in development that you will deploy to. Same products, and same versions. Also same configuration options where applicable.

You are right, but I'm patching some databases that blew up during weekend, I'm debugging code from my IDE outside Docker, and many many other etcs that doesn't make sense to explain here.
I will try to definitely reproduce this deploying the exact same stack in my local. Given your answer, it doesn't make sense that this app's unit tests hasn't blew up before and they blew up now after bumping up the mysql connectors and the underlying data base version.

This seems to assume that the OP is using Timestamp.toString(), which I don’t believe to be the case (and if it had been the case, they should stop using Timestamp at all). Also Timestamp.toString() has always left out zeroes in the decimal beyond the first decimal. It does include .0 if the decimal part is 0. The values in the question without any decimal part at all (like 2018-05-29 21:02:29) do not come from Timestamp.toString(). So this answer seems to me to be misunderstood.
